# Broken packages error when installing libdvd-pkg

Tags: dependencies

I'm new to Linux and trying to add DVD playback. I keep getting a broken packages error. I'm running 16.04 LTS.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkw4u.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

And if it doesn't work, install synaptic and try to repair the broken packages with it.